# React JS with mysql tutorials

Tags: mysql, reactjs

Hi I am new to react js and I am looking at tutorials for reactjs with mysql (basic user registeration and login). I tried pretty much many tutorials but they are all failing for one reason or the other. Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to use a Javascript View Framework ( ReactJs ) with a database related technology ( Mysql ). For your user registration system you would need a small backend implementation done using Php, Node, etc..that works in coordination with the database technology.

Using React & Mysql as stand alone technologies won't be sufficient for your exercise.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Agheorghiesei Andrei-Klauss. I tried to create an API (REST) in PHP and then tried to implement the same in REACT app. It is a normal CURD operation and works fine. :-) I can share the code if that helps someone.